# Timeout from a for loop

Tags: c++

I'm working with UDP Server and Client, and I'm sending data from Client to Server vise versa. But as you guys know with UDP its "Send and pray" and hope it arrives.

I want to have a for loop that quit if the time is over 'X' seconds even though its not finished. Because you cannot guarantee that everything will arrive.

Is there a simple way doing that without adding to much to my for loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < split ; i++){
    iResult = recvfrom(RecvSocket, RecvBuf, BufLen, 0, (SOCKADDR *)& SenderAddr, &SenderAddrSize);

    cout << "Receiving " << BufLen << endl;
    sum += BufLen;

    //IF X seconds goes cancel loop with
    //timeout something something
}
```

Comment: get time, check time difference, break from loop

Comment: It is OS specific. Standard C++11 does not know about sockets. So read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) if coding for Linux. See [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), [udp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html),etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can do the time stuff portably using C++11 time functionality, e.g. std::chrono etc. If you want to wake up from a blocking read, you need select or poll or relatives (epoll/pselect).

Answer (score 0):

Set an alarm/timer before the loop starts.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the exact timeout, this could be a very simple approach:

```
const int max = 100;
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < split; i++){
    iResult = recvfrom(RecvSocket, RecvBuf, BufLen, 0, (SOCKADDR *)& SenderAddr, &SenderAddrSize);

    cout << "Receiving " << BufLen << endl;
    sum += BufLen;

    count++;
    if (count == max)
    {
        //something something
        break;
    }
    Sleep(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const double MAX_SECONDS = 30;
double start = omp_get_wtime();

for (int i = 0; i < split ; i++)
{  
 iResult = recvfrom(RecvSocket, RecvBuf, BufLen, 0, (SOCKADDR *)& SenderAddr, &SenderAddrSize);

cout << "Receiving " << BufLen << endl;
sum += BufLen;

double end = omp_get_wtime();

//IF X seconds goes cancel loop with
//timeout something something
if((end - start) > MAX_SECONDS)
   break;
}
```

This will break the loop after 30 seconds.
More info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3282fe5.aspx

Comment: I tired this, and I get Timeout right away, I set MAX_SECONDS TO 30000 dosnt matter :/

Comment: Did you include #include <omp.h>? What is the output of end-start?